# Listview of sent and received sms color change on scroll

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Hi I am developing an android SMS app where I want to display sent and received SMS in two different colors on a `ListView`. If its sent SMS, I am changing color in the adapter. If lets say there are 10 items on ListView, the below code works fine.

```
    if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
    {
    //received sms  

    }
    else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("2"))
    {
       //sent sms
        msg.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D5F7C3"));
        msgdt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDF8C7"));
     }
```

But on scrolling it, the 11th item still remains as previous view color. The colors in the listview keeps changing as I scroll back and forth. I have added `android:cacheColorHint="#000000"` for the `ListView`. Not sure where I am going wrong. How do I resolve this? Please Help.

Thanks!

Comment: can you please paste your `getView` method for more clarity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using custom layout for view in list item.

So now what happens is that when you using custom layout so it will inflate the layout and it will be used again for next items.

so do as check condition in custom adapter's getview() is that something similar to this..

```
if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
{
    //received sms  
    msg.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D5F7C3"));
    msgdt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDF8C7"));
    //Set colors for Recieved SMS.

 }
else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("2"))
{
   //sent sms
    msg.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D5F7C3"));
    msgdt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDF8C7"));

   //Set Colors for Sent SMS
 }
```

it will work for you.

(its just code logic representation so check criteria needs to be set by you.)

Hope it Helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain states of each listview item according to that assign color to listitem.

**Update-**

Same problem was happening with me for checkbox in list.it was automatically changing.

```
  public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private List<String> mName;
private List<Drawable> mIcon;
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private DataHelper mDataHelper;
private List<String> DBappName;
boolean[] checkBoxState;
private ArrayList<Boolean> itemChecked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();


public ListAdapter(Context mContext, List<String> Name, List<Drawable> appIcon, ) {
    this.mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.mContext=mContext;
    this.mName=Name;
    this.mIcon=Icon;

    mDataHelper=new DataHelper(mContext);
    DBappName=new ArrayList<String>();
    DBappName=mDataHelper.selectName();

    /***Initialization***/

    for (int i = 0; i < this.getCount(); i++) {
        itemChecked.add(i, false); // initializes all items value with false
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < DBappName.size(); i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<mName.size();j++){
            if(DBappName.get(i).equals(mName.get(j))){
                itemChecked.add(j, true); 
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mName.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder mHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_menu, null);
        mHolder = new ViewHolder();

        mHolder.mText=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Name);
        mHolder.mImage=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Icon);
        mHolder.mCheckBoxLock=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mCheckbox);
        convertView.setTag(mHolder);

    } else {
        mHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    mHolder.mText.setText(mName.get(position));
    mHolder.mImage.setImageDrawable(mIcon.get(position));
    mHolder.mCheckBoxLock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
                itemChecked.set(position, true);
                mDataHelper.insert(mName.get(position));
            }else{
                itemChecked.set(position, false);
                mDataHelper.delete(mName.get(position));
            }
        }
    });
    mHolder.mCheckBoxLock.setChecked(itemChecked.get(position)); // this will Check or Uncheck the
    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    private TextView mText;
    private ImageView mImage;
    private CheckBox mCheckBoxLock;
}
```

}